# given a csv like string, how to load into Spark dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a string, the format is the same as csv, with first row as column name and rest of the records be data.
How do I use pyspark to load this string into data frame.

```
str = '''
        sale_id, cust_name, amount
        111, abc, 10000
        222, bcd, 15000
      '''
```

Answer (score 6):

Found answer:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = io.StringIO(str)
pd_df = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",")
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df)
display(df)
```